# How to align a paragraph text to an image in the middle

Tags: html, css

I basiclly wanna make the same as the image shown,where the text Love us on facebook align in the middle of the image:

[image]

Here my html:

```
  <p><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-184" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/facebook.png" alt="facebook" width="60" height="60">Love us on Facebook</p>
```

I thought of using vertical alignment to middle but it is not working.

At the moment, mine looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the other vertical alignment values? i.e. `vertical-alignment:baseline;` or `vertical-alignment:sub;`

Comment: vertical-align should be set to img withouth display reset nor float values, can you add your css ... else we need to guess

Comment: Tried but it didn't work

Comment: Use vertical alignment as initial in your image.
.wp-image-184 {
    vertical-align: inherit;
}

Comment: Thanksit works with the initial alignment @Elton Sousa

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `vertical-align:middle` to the image:

```css
.wp-image-184 { vertical-align:middle; }
```

```html
<p><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-184" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/facebook.png" alt="facebook" width="60" height="60">Love us on Facebook</p>
```

Comment: basicly correct, but what do we know about full css used here ? **he said he used this value and it did not worked** we are missing something in the question

Comment: @GCyrillus, I'm guessing he used it on the p tag as if he used it on the image, he wouldn't get what he got in the second image

Comment: ;) like you said a guess , but maybe `p` has `display:table-cell` too ... the flex model would be an answser too. The op should give more details